# AutoCompleteTextView in a Listview - notifyDataSetChanged() resets it

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, autocompletetextview

First item in my ListView may be the search - AutoCompleteTextView . But sadly when ListView gets adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  - what was typed there is being erased and AutoCompleteTextView looses focus. The keyboard stays but I can no longer type it until I press this view again and type it .

But. this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() happens alot - what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put AutoCompleteTextView before / outside ListView ?

This should update only the itens in the ListView but with the AutoCompleteTextView isolated.
I have almost the same implementation and worked for me.

```
<LinearLayout />   
    <AutoCompleteTextView /> =====> Filtering here (I guess).
        <ListView /> =============> notifyDataSetChanged().
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

dNiel Liqskk is right ....
but if you want to go for a second option....

You can add **autocompletetextview as header view**..